# Simple NAT64 with Jool and Debian 11

Tags: debian, ipv6

How does one simply enable NAT64 on a Debian 11 system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the packages `jool-dkms` and `jool-tools`. These are only available per default since Debian 11 / Bullseye. Be aware that this installs a whole bunch of development tools, kernel-headers etc. This might be a security issue on an edge device. It also required 312 Mb of disk space on a dedicated router without too many packages. If this is not acceptable, there's still [tayga](http://www.litech.org/tayga/)

Then create a directory `/etc/jool` and a file `/etc/jool/jool.conf` with the following content:

```
{
        "instance": "default",
        "framework": "netfilter",
        "global": {
                "pool6": "64:ff9b::/96"
        }
}
```

Be aware that, even if you configure your firewall via `iptables`, the underlying `framework` is Netfilter. The same goes for the Jool Website, where they have Netfilter and iptables examples.
The `default` instance means that you don't have to specify it explicitly when using the jool CLI tool.
Otherwise just specify your NAT64 prefix as `pool6` and you're good to go. The example uses the IANA-reserved *well-known prefix*, but you can also use a [prefix from your own network](https://serverfault.com/questions/1073884/choice-of-nat64-prefix).

Start jool via `systemctl start jool` and test from an internal system with `ping 64:ff9b::1.1.1.1` Adjust the prefix if necessary and **don't** use the example from the Jool website, that won't work. I forgot to check beforehand, so run `systemctl enable jool`, just to be save.

You'll almost certainly want DNS64 as well: check [O'Reilly](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/dns-and-bind/9781449308025/ch04.html) or the Jool website. [Their example](https://www.jool.mx/en/dns64.html) has ACLs, in case you don't have firewall on / in front of your DNS server.